# Is there a way to convert a pandas dataframe into a data tree in python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns as follows:

```
col1   |                   col 2
----------------------------------------------------------
1. 100 | T89000/T79000/T78001/T77001/T76001/T55000/T54000 |
2. 200 | T89000/T79000/T78001/T77001/T76001/T55000/T54000 |
3. 300 | T89000/T79000/T78001/T77001/T76001/T55000/T54000 |
4. 400 | T89000/T79000/T78001/T77001/T76001/T55000/T54000 |
5. 500 | T89000/T79000/T78001/T77001/T76001/T55000/T54000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to convert these two columns into a data tree similar to the one which we can do using the data.tree package in R language. Please tell me how can I do this?

Also, I need the values in Col1 to be the children of the nodes created using col2.

Comment: Guys please help! I need some leads! This is the only platform from where I can expect some help!

Comment: I think the issue is that while there are many people who know `pandas` well and many people who know `r` well, there are a small number who know both of them well enough and have knowledge of the `data.tree` library to answer this question. I did a quick look and my initial reaction is you can get something *like* that with a MultiIndex, or perhaps using `networkx` but you probably wont have a lot of the functionality specifically built into `data.tree`. It's unclear exactly what the "similar" requirement means.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for answering! So, basically I just want to construct a hierarchical structure (say a python dictionary) so that I can access each element in col2 with its subsequent children in col1